XML deserialization using XPath rather than fixed element name for a property in c#?
If I have a xml like this
<Form_1_1>
    <Body>
        <Code>123</Code>
    </Body>
</Form_1_1>

I can easily deserialize it to this class structure
[XmlRoot("Form_1_1")]
public class Form_1_1
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Body")]
    public Body Body { get; set; }
}

public class Body
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")]
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

But is there any way to map the element in such a way that I can directly reach to element Code skipping Body element? So basically deserialize the XML to this object structure
[XmlRoot("Form_1_1")]
public class Form_1_1
{
    [XmlElement(?????????)] // Something go here?
    public string Code { get; set; }
}

The only way possible that I can think of is by using the xpath inside XmlElement attribute rather than a fixed element name, but that is not allowed.
So is there any way to achieve this or is it simply not possible?
Update
I know it is possible with LINQ to XML but I cannot use it because it involves defining mapping of every element and attribute which is not possible for my case because my XML is quite long.
I posted just a small part of the XML in my question for the sake of the simplicity but my real XML is quite long so I can only stick with the XmlSerializer.Deserialize method which I am using currently.

Check Reading XML Data using XPathDocument and XmlDocument. Using LINQ-to-XML is probably easier though

You can try LINQ to XML API. It is available in the .Net Framework since 2007.
It is very flexible and powerful.
The mapping is done via .Element("Code") method call. If needed you can easily add additional Form_1_1 class members and the mapping.
c#
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Form_1_1>
            <Body>
                <Code>123</Code>
            </Body>
        </Form_1_1>");

    Form_1_1 form_1_1 = xdoc.Descendants("Body")
        .Select(x => new Form_1_1()
        {
            Code = x.Element("Code")?.Value
        }).SingleOrDefault();
    
    Console.WriteLine(form_1_1);
}

public class Form_1_1
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
}


This approach I know but it is not practical for my case because my XML is quite long. I posted the small part of my XML just for the example, so it would not be possible for me to map every property one by one like you posted. I am using XmlSerializer to deserialize the XML which is convenient and practical way for me and so I was looking for some way to achieve it using the standard Deserialize method

Using linq is not really the object Deserialization

Java's APIs support XPath in decorations. .Net doesn't support such functionality. Your tradeoff is a replacement of [XmlElement(ElementName = "Code")] decoration with the Code = x.Element("Code")?.Value

But I do not only have Code element. I have many elements as well as many nested structure, so it will become cumbersome if I try to reach to all the nested levels with LINQ to XML approach. So basically what I asked in the question is not at all possible with .Net, right?
